# AJAX returns the complete HTML site instead the JSON object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I finally could receive a response from my AJAX PHP call.
But now in return I get my full HTML site instead of a JSON object or string.
What is wrong here?

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "mysite.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {select:requestStr},
  dataType: "html"
});

request.done(function( data ) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

I send a simple string to my php class. This is what I get from the response-text in my developer tool from the browser:

```
data=Test
```

On PHP site I just return that respone:

```
<?php
    $myData = array();
    $myData['data'] = "test";
    if (isset($_POST)) {
        $myData['data'] = $_POST;
    }
    echo json_encode($myData);
    exit();
?>
```

And this is the console.log from the response:

```
"<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html>\r\n<head> ... </html>\"Test\""
```

**EDIT**

I only need the end of the response and that is `"Test"` but not the whole HTML file.

**UPDATE**
I extracted my PHP class and wrote a Little Version like the PHP code above.
But now my response is an empty object `{"data":[]}`

Comment: Is that really the entire contents of `mysite.php`? (And you are missing the content-type header).

Comment: from mysite.php what are you returning can you show

Comment: make sure your PHP script does not have any HTML on the top just use the <?php ..  ?> to have the code and return the JSON.

Comment: If you have any HTML written after echo you need to stop the script by putting a exit() call after echo;

Comment: @Quentin No not really. It is a PHP class but I thought only to print the important part. And yes or no I have no Content-type Header in here.

Comment: Hm ... the exit has no effect. Ajax returns the full HTML site anyway. :-(

Comment: please post content of `mysite.php`

Comment: That's funny. I have extracted that Little function from my PHP class to post it here in a single PHP File and now I receive an empty string. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Hey put type="Json" instead of the "text"

Answer (score -1):

Put a `exit();` after `echo json_encode($myData);`